# UITableView Footer height varrying with phone size

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have created a custom view in `nib`. Height is fixed for this `view`. i.e. 73.

Now I am setting it as a `UITableView` Footer view.

Here is my code:

```
func configureTableFooterView() {
    let footerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FooterView", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as? PlotTableFooterView

    footerView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.mTableView.frame.width, height: CGFloat(kTableFooterHeight))

    self.mTableView.tableFooterView = footerView

    self.mTableView.tableFooterView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.mTableView.frame.width, height: CGFloat(kTableFooterHeight))

    self.mTableView.tableFooterView = footerView
}
```

Here is screenshot of `footerView`. Pink `View` is my footer View.
[image]

Comment: I assume that `kTableFooterHeight` is set to `73`. Do you have any constraints set in your FooterView nib file?

Comment: @LGP yes. In my tableFooterView nib there is UIView. And I have added following constraints: leading trailing top bottom height.

I am making and API request and until I get response number of rows is zero in table view. I wonder is this is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you set the height in your code, try removing any height and top/bottom constraints in the nib.

Answer (score 0):

Enable resizing (translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) to make frame size effective.

Try this,

```
footerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```